# Como estilizar a scroll bar e manter as setinhas (para cima e para baixo)?

Tags: html, css

Quando eu estilizo a *scrollbar*, as setinhas de subir e descer desaparecem. Tem como manter elas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Scroll</title>
  <style>
    /*========== ESTILIZAÇÃO DA BARRA DE SCROLL==========*/
    
    body::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 15px;
    }
    
    body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: #e9e9e9;
    }
    
    body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgb(0, 87, 0);
      border-radius: 100px;
      border: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
    }
    
    body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background-color: rgb(3, 49, 3);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 2000px">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

O objetivo é deixar as setinhas padrão após fazer as estilizações na barra, como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu acho que você vai precisar fazê-las (com css) por conta própria, aqui tem alguns exemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47576815/8839059

Comment: Não tem como, pq, a partir do momento em que vc altera o scroll bar, o _user agent_ (navegador) _abandona_ as setas.

Answer (score -2):

Segue um exemplo de como estilizar as setas.

```
/* Up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement
{
  border-width: 0 7px 14px 7px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #404040 transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:hover
{
  border-color: transparent transparent #505050 transparent;
}


/* Down */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment
{
  border-width: 14px 7px 0 7px;
  border-color: #404040 transparent transparent transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:hover
{
  border-color: #505050 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: por favor responda em portugues e formate o codigo